# when using union that uses values from a form it creates a error?

Tags: ms-access, union

I have this union statement when I try to take parameters from a form and pass it to a union select statement it says too many parameters. This is using `MS ACCESS`.

```
SELECT Statement FROM table 1 where Date = Between [Forms]![DateIN]![StartDate]
UNION
SELECT Statement FROM table 2 where Date = Between [Forms]![DateIN]![StartDate]
```

This is the first time I am using windows DB applications to do Database apps. I am Linux type of person and always use `MySQL` for my projects but for this one have to use MS Access.

Is there anther way to pass parameters to UNION Statement because this method of defining values in a form can work on Single SELECT statements. But I don't know why this problem exist.

Answer (score 1):

[Between](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/between-and-operator-HP001032212.aspx) *"Determines whether the value of an expression falls within a specified range of values"* like this ...

```
expr [Not] Between value1 And value2
```

But your query only gives it one value ... `Between [Forms]![DateIN]![StartDate]`

So you need to add `And` plus another date value ...

```
Between [Forms]![DateIN]![StartDate] And some_other_date
```

Also `Date` is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html).  If you're using it as a field name, enclose it in brackets to avoid confusing the db engine: `[Date]`

If practical, rename the field to avoid similar problems in the future.

And as Gord pointed out, you must also bracket table names which include a space.  The same applies to field names.

Comment: If the table names really are `table 1` and `table 2` then they need to be enclosed in square brackets too.

Answer (score 0):

Still getting problems when using this method of calling the values or dates from the form to be used on the UNION statement. Here is the actual query that I am trying to use.

I don't want to recreate the wheel but I was thinking that if the `Date()` can be used with `between Date() and Date()-6` to represent a 7 days range then I might have to right a module that takes the values from the for and then returns the values that way I can do something like `Sdate()` and `Edate()` then this can be used with `Between Sdate() and Edate()`.

I have not tried this yet but this can be my last option I don't even know if it will work but it is worth a try. But before i do that i want to try all the resources that Access can help me make my life easy such as its OO Stuff it has for helping DB programmers.

```
SELECT  
    "Expenditure" as [TransactionType], *  
FROM 
    Expenditures 
WHERE 
   (((Expenditures.DateofExpe) Between [Forms]!Form1![Text0] and  [Forms]![Form1]![Text11]))

UNION 

SELECT 
    "Income" as [TransactionType], *  
FROM 
    Income 
WHERE 
    (((Income.DateofIncom)  Between [Forms]!Form1![Text0] and [Forms]![Form1]![Text11]  ));
```

Access VBA has great power but I don't want to use it as of yet as it will be hard to modify changes for a user that does not know how to program. trying to keep this DB app simple as possible for a dumb user to fully operate.

Any comments is much appreciated.